# How are results guaranteed in algorithms that include intermediate approximation?

Tags: reference-request, algorithms, approximation, decimal-expansion, floating-point

Let me elucidate this vague question with an example. Consider for example the following Gauss sum of roots of unity

$N=(e^{2\pi i/5} + e^{2\pi i/4} e^{4\pi i/5} + e^{4\pi i/4} e^{8\pi i/5} + e^{6\pi i/4} e^{16\pi i/5})^4$.

We know from Galois theory that this is expression is in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. We could devise an algorithm to determine what this Gaussian integer is:

Approximate $e^{2\pi ij/5}$ via a decimal expansion to $m$ decimal places and use this approximation to compute $N$ while keeping the $4$-th roots of unity as formal symbols. Then round the coefficients to the nearest integers. As $m\rightarrow \infty$, we have that the decimal expansions should approach the correct integers, but

**Question:** If we are trying to determine a runtime for this algorithm, it must include $m$. Is there an effectively computable $m$ such that we can guarantee that the 'rounding' step returns the correct integers? I am questioning this in general, not just for this specific example: can there be guarantees in such algorithms?

---

For example, wolfram alpha uses a similar approximation, and returns -14.9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999 +
20.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 i. I want to say that this guarantees the expression is $-15+20i$, but is this true?

Comment: If you know that the result is an integer, and if the analysis of the error propagation gives an error smaller $1/3$, then you know that rounding will produce the correct result.

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by analysis of error propagation?

Comment: You know that the complex exponentials are correct up to the last bit. The product of complex numbers loses 2 mantissa bits (at worst). Each sum loses 1 bit, so 4 bits in a left-to-right summation. The 4 power as the square of the square loses again about 4 bits. So in total the last 11 bits of 52 mantissa bits (for 64bit double floats) are unreliable, which gives a good safety buffer against rounding to the wrong integer.

Comment: Even in single precision, 11 of 23 bit is still a comfortable safety margin, giving a relative error smaller than $5·10^{-4}$. As the error estimate is relative, the size of the result also matters. Here in the worst case it is $5^4=625$, with the real result one decimal smaller, thus this comes close to the limit for single precision.